# Заполнить поля случайными данными в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть простая таблица: `id, name, text, image, date`.

Как можно заполнить поля случайными данными (300 шт.) ?

Данные в полях (`id, name, text, image, date`) могут быть одинаковыми например: `Название статьи, текст статьи, image.jpg, 1418939449`.

Comment: Какие форматы колонок? int, varchar(?)  и т.д.

Comment: Я бы использовал PHP. Создать несколько массивов: `$names, $texts, $images, $dates`, а потом в цикле выбирать из них в случайном порядке и вставлять в базу.

Comment: @cyadvert `id=int, name=varchar, text=varchar, image=varchar, date=int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы предложил такой вариант:

Создать несколько массивов и в цикле заносить данные из них.

```
$rowsToCreate = 300;
$names = Array("name1", "name2", "name3", "name4");
$texts = Array("text1", "text2", "text3", "text4");
$images = Array("image1", "image2", "image3", "image4");
do {
    $sqlStr = "INSERT INTO [table] (name, text, image, date) VALUES ('" . array_rand($names) . "', '" . array_rand($texts) . "', '" . array_rand($images) . "', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 0-CAST(RAND()*100 AS SIGNED) DAY))";
    [запустить SQL]
    $rowsToCreate--;
} while ($rowsToCreate>=0);
```

Я не особенно понял почему `date` в формате `int`, а не, например `bigint`. В моем примере будет вставлена случайная дата в диапазоне от 100 дней назад до сейчас... Исправьте под нужное Вам.

Вообще все очень зависит от того, насколько безбашенными Вам нужны данные.
Можно имена генерировать простым `md5()` с выдергиванием цифр.
Тексты можно брать из какой-нибудь директории с `txt` файлами. Создать папку, накидать туда текстов из какой-нить библиотеки, и брать рандомно файлы.
Тоже самое можно сделать с картинками... Использоввать папку `/Pictures` (если Вы на винде)...
Много вариантов :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ немножко изменил `array_rand()` потому что вместо текста выводилось 1,2,3 и дату и все работает.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker
это не оно ?
я думаю самое распространенное решение